# django install warning and manage.py runserver failure

Tags: django

I'm trying to work through the django tutorial, and seem to have a problem with the django installation (on Windows 7). I've installed Python, and pip, and installed Django via pip, at which point I got this output:

Downloading/unpacking Django
  Downloading Django-1.5.1.tar.gz (8.0MB): 8.0MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Django

```
warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under dir
```

ectory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under direct
ory '*'
Installing collected packages: Django
  Running setup.py install for Django

```
warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under dir
```

ectory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under direct
ory '*'
Successfully installed Django
Cleaning up...

Since the messages were only warnings, I proceeded with trying to run django From within the project folder, I issue: 
C:\data\spark2\spark\spark_project>python manage.py runserver
and receive the message:
ImportError: No module named debug_toolbar

then the command prompt is displayed again.
I've tried uninstalling and re-installing Django, to no avail.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try to install it with `pip install` or `easy_install`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to install [`django-debug-toolbar`](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) which your project requires.

Running `pip install django-debug-toolbar` should fix that import error.

Ideally projects come with a `Requirements.txt` file that contains the output of `pip freeze`. If you have one, you can install all of the requirements by running `pip install -r Requirements.txt`